# Rails model validation: How to make sure a attribute is in a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Hi I have a `job` model which has an string attribute called `category`. In the front end, I have a form with a dropbox where a user can fill out the `category` attribute with the selected value from the list. This is good enough front end validation for me, but now how will I do backend validation for the model?

I have dont other validations in the past for example:

```
validates :name, :presence => true
```

But is there anyway I can do something like

```
validates :category, :in => {"Food", "Drink", "Rental"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
validates :category, :inclusion => { :in => %w(Food Drink Rental) }
```

Or shorter:

```
validates :category, :inclusion => %w(Food Drink Rental)
```

Everything is in the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates).